# Android Testing using UI Automator

Tags: android, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I am very new to Android Testing. I have written a small test case to see how testing is done. I am using **UI Automator** in **Android Studio**.
Below is my code -

```
private UiObject2 waitForObject(BySelector selector) throws InterruptedException {
    UiObject2 object = null;
    int timeout = 30000;
    object = mDevice.wait(Until.findObject(selector), timeout);
    return object;
}

@org.junit.Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    openApp("com.test.ex.chat");
    UiObject2 editText = waitForObject(By.res(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getPackageName(),"et_ChatScreen"));
    editText.setText("GDC");
    UiObject2 buttonSend = waitForObject(By.res(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext().getPackageName(),"btn_send"));
    mDevice.pressBack(); //error here
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    buttonSend.click(); //error here
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

The problem is that when i execute the test case i get an error when a button is pressed.
The error which i get is `java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission` and i get this error when any **device button** is **pressed** by the code or when `buttonSend.click();` is executed.
I have also given `INJECT_EVENTS` `permission` in the `manifest`
I don't know what's wrong here and i need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you add permission in manifest?

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />

Comment: yes i have added both of the permissions

Answer (score 0):

Try adding GrantPermissionRule from JUnit in the test class.

For Example

```
@Rule
public GrantPermissionRule mRuntimePermissionRule = 
GrantPermissionRule.grant(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

Hope it will work.If needed you can give any more required permission in the same rule itself